# CSS scale3d() not working on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, css, transform, scale

As the title says. I can't get the scale3d tranform to work on Android 4.4.2 (webview). Tested on a real device and in an emulator.
However on a S3 Mini with Android 4.2.2 it runs as expected. Also according to the website http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d 3d transforms should work on Android 4.4.2.

Here is some code I used for testing ([fiddle link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EfbKtAxh2fn1uEBaPnKH)). The blue box should be four times bigger than the red one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .yoyo{
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .yoyo.blue{
        background-color: blue;
        right: 0;
        transform: scale3d(4,4,1);
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(4,4,1);
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="yoyo"></div>

<div class="yoyo blue"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turned out that it didn't work on the emulator because I forgot to add the '-webkit-' prefix during testing. Now with the webkit-prefix it works on all emulators I've tested so far. But it still doesn't work on the real device. The real device is using a Cyanogenmod 7 ROM, therefore I think it is a problem with that special device/setup.